# How to generate PEM or x509 compliant certificate from https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/certs?

Tags: powershell, google-oauth, rsa, public-key, google-openid

Examples using powershell use `[Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2]` to sign data. The data present here is in the form of what I believe is a [Json Web Key](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7517) (JWK).

How do you convert a JWK to a compliant cert that can be used by `X509Certifate2`?

Comment: There's nothing to be "generated". That json blob _is_ the public key corresponding to the signing key used by Google's public OAuth2 token service.

Comment: Maybe the question I'm looking for an answer for is how do I convert it to a pem.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs gives you the X509 certificates in PEM format, but I believe this endpoint is deprecated.